# Fit a (big sized) table (properly)

Tags: tables

In the following image, the problem I am dealing with:

[image]

I would like to fit the table in the image in my text, but I don't like the outcome produced by \includegraphics. Hence, I guess the best solution would be to reproduce the table itself. Being it quite big, the result I would get putting it horizontally (assuming that it is even possible to do) wouldn't be nice either. Would it be better to put it vertically?

As far as the code to reproduce the table is concerned, I imagine it could be something similar to

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{booktabs} % horizontal lines, such as \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule
\usepackage{tabularx} % tabularx environment
\usepackage{siunitx} % S type columns to improve alignment of numbers
\usepackage{threeparttable} % tablenotes environment and \tnote commend
\usepackage{makecell} % \thead command for column headers with manual line breaks

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\begin{document}



\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}

   
      \caption{Participant Characteristics}
   
      \label{tab:key}
   
         \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hangindent=6pt}X r@{\;}l r@{\;}l S[table-format=1.3]@{}}
    
              \toprule
    
              \thead[bl]{Variables} 
       
               & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead[b]{More \\experienced \\ investors}} 
       
              &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead[b]{Less \\experienced \\ investors}} 
    
              &  {\thead[b]{P-Value\tnote{*}}}\\
     
             \midrule
             Percentage who had             previously invested in          the stock market       
                                         & \multicolumn{2}{c}{78.50\%} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{36.78\%} & .001  \\
            Years of business work          experience        
                                &  6.35         & (6.00)             & 1.28         & (2.14)              & .001  \\
            Age     
                                    &  30.46        & (5.83)             &  20.11       & (2.67)              & .001  \\
            Number of courses taken             that discussed investing            in mutual funds or the          stock market        
                                &  1.58         & (1.70)              &  .95        & (1.16)             & .001  \\             Familiarity with mutual             funds (1 = not at all           familiar, 7 = very          familiar)   
                                & 4.59      & (1.61)              & 3.63        & (4.96)             & .011  \\             Importance in investing in          mutual funds or the             stock market (1 = not           at all important, 7 =           very important) 
                                & 5.61      & (1.39)              &  5.24       & (1.31)             & .016  \\             Peers' views of investing           in mutual funds or the          stock market (1 = not           at all desirable, 7 =           very desirable)         &  5.14         & (1.26)             &  4.64        & (1.71)         & .009  \\
    
              \bottomrule
                 \end{tabularx}
    
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
        \small
            \item[*] All tests are t-tests (one-tailed) except for the percentage investing, which is a chi-square test.
    \end{tablenotes}
    
        \end{threeparttable} \end{table} \end{document}
```

of course suitably modified. How can I modify the above code in order to get the six columns I need instead of the four produced by it (for example)?

My (very naive, since I am a beginner to say the least; I was just modifying a template I thought could work out) approach:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{booktabs} % horizontal lines, such as \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule
\usepackage{tabularx} % tabularx environment
\usepackage{siunitx} % S type columns to improve alignment of numbers
\usepackage{threeparttable} % tablenotes environment and \tnote commend
\usepackage{makecell} % \thead command for column headers with manual line breaks

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\tiny
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\toprule
Panel A: Percentage of Participants Willing to Invest in Mutual Funds\\
 & Small Set Condition2 & Large Set Condition2 & Difference & Chi-Square & P-Value \\
\midrule
forza & $F$ & newton \\
energia & $E$ & joule \\
tensione & $V$ & volt \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: There are several approaches to make the table fit the page: you can use a smaller font size, use a smaller value for `\tabcolsep` (which is  6pt by default), use `tabularx` (which you do in your code), adjust locally the margins with the `adjustwidth`  environment (from the `changepage` package).

Comment: How is the table in your MWE related to the table in the image? What did you try so far in order to get the table in the screenshot?

Comment: They are not related content-wise, it was just supposed to be a (tentative of) a template. I tried out a very simple approach, reading http://www.lorenzopantieri.net/LaTeX_files/ArteLaTeX.pdf, but it doesn't seem to be the right one. I will provide it above.

Comment: Well, since you already have a code for a different table, why don't you try to adjust the code to this paring in the contents would be a first step in the right direction.

Comment: I will, no problem.

Comment: I think I almost made it, I will provide the result. Thank you leandriis for the encouragement in doing better!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'll like it:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, % horizontal lines, such as \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule
            makecell, % \thead command for column headers with manual line breaks
            multirow, % multirowcell 
            tabularx, % tabularx environment
            threeparttable} % tablenotes environment and \tnote commend
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\renewcommand\TPTtagStyle{\bfseries}
\usepackage{siunitx} % S type columns to improve alignment of numbers

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \sisetup{table-align-text-after=false}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \small
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Participant Characteristics\tnote{1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}    L  
                                    S[table-format= 2.2{\%}]
                                    S[table-format= 2.2{\%}]
                                    S[table-format=-2.2{\%}]
                                    S[table-format= 1.2]
                                    S[table-format= 1.3]
                            @{}}   
                                
    \toprule
\multicolumn{6}{l}{Panel A: Percentage of Participants Willing to Invest in Mutual Funds}\\
    \midrule
    &   {\thead{Small Set\\ Condition 2}} 
        &   {\thead{Small Set\\ Condition 2}} 
            &   {\thead{Difference}} 
                &   {\thead{Chi-Square}} 
                    &   {\thead{P-Value}}           \\
    \midrule
Less experienced investors/ no categories\tnote{3} $(b=61)$
    & 93.1 \% 
        &   71.9 \%
            &  21.2 \% 
                &   4.64 \%
                    &   0.031                       \\
Moderate experienced investors/ no categories $(n=113)$
    & 86.1 \,\%
        &   71.9 \,\%
            &   7.4 \,\%
                &   1.06 \,\%
                    &   0.303                       \\
More experienced investors/ no categories $(b=93)$
    & 66.7 \,\%
        &   78.6 \,\%
            &  -14.6 \,\%
                &   2.28 \,\%
                    &   0.108                       \\
    \midrule
... \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft,online]\footnotesize
    \item[1]    After review the investment fund choices, participant were asked whether or not they wanted to invest in one or more these mutual funds at the present time.
    \item[2]    Participants in the small (large) set condition were present with 5 (50) mutual funds from 5 categories: aggressive growth funds, growth and income stock funds, growth and income stock, and bond funds, and bond funds.
    \item[3]    Participants in the No Categories (Categories) condition received the mutual funds without (with) risk categories labels.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}    
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest an alternative approach that attempts to reduce repetition:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{booktabs} % horizontal lines, such as \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule
\usepackage{tabularx} % tabularx environment
\usepackage{siunitx} % S type columns to improve alignment of numbers
\usepackage{threeparttable} % tablenotes environment and \tnote commend
\usepackage{makecell} % \thead command for column headers with manual line breaks

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}

        

\begin{table}
\caption[your caption text]{your caption text\textsuperscript{1}}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
\caption{Percentage of Participants Willing to Invest in Mutual Funds}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hangindent=6pt}X 
                             *{3}{S[table-format=-2.1, table-space-text-post={\%}]}
                             *{2}{S[table-format=1.3]}}
\toprule
 & {\thead{Small Set\\ Condition\tnote{2}}} & {\thead{Large Set\\ Condition}} & {\thead{Difference}} & {\thead{Chi-Square}} & {\thead{P-Value}} \\
\midrule
some lengthy text in the first column\tnote{3} & 11.1\% & 11.1\% & 11.1\% & 1.11 & .111\\
some lengthy text in the first column & 11.1\% & 11.1\% & 11.1\% & 1.11 & .111\\
some lengthy text in the first column & 11.1\% & 11.1\% & 11.1\% & 1.11 & .111\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}
\bigskip

\begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
\caption{second cubcaption}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hangindent=6pt}X *{2}{S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=1.3]}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Small Set Conditions}}  &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Large Set Conditions}}  \\
\cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
 & {\thead{Chi-Square}} & {\thead{P-Value}} & {\thead{Chi-Square}} & {\thead{P-Value}} \\
 \midrule
some lengthy text in the first column & 1.11 & .111 & 1.11 & .111\\
some lengthy text in the first column & 1.11 & .111 & 1.11 & .111\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{subtable}
\begin{tablenotes} \footnotesize
\item[1] some table note text
\item[2] another a lot longer table note text which needs a line break another a lot longer table note text which needs a line break
\item[3] some table note text
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```